# Two submit button in one form for same POST method/action

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I want to use two submit button in one form. Both Submit will go to same POST method. But one submit button will do all tasks in POST method and then **go to a list page**, and the other submit button will do all tasks in POST method and **reload the form as blank form**.

Here are the buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="saveNdone" value="Save & Done" />
<input type="submit" name="saveNnew" value="Save & Load New" />
```

I am using JSP & Spring 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple submit buttons but you would need to involve some javascript to tweak the functionality

You can set your form to be submitted normally with the first submit button but when the second one is licked you need to submit it to a different url. In such case you would need:

```js
$("#secondSubmitButton").click(function(e){

 // let's stop default action first
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $("#yourForm").attr('action', 'http://yournewsubmiterl.com/somelink.php').submit();

});
```

Comment: or if you want the same action url, and then redirect, than on second submit button click you can add a hidden field and add redirect data. then when page is reloaded check if $_POST['your-hidden-field'] is set and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_name.asp). This should be exactly what you need and gets along without JavaScript.